# Array_search in PHP returning 26 as Key for values in index 36-61

Tags: php

I am using Array_search in PHP to write a function like **C/C++:atoi** but with different base system. I am passing a string and the array_Search is returning 26 as Key for values in index 36-61. Here is the code.

```
$mergeArr = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('0', '9'), range('A', 'Z'));
$newArr = str_split('dz7A');
$intArr = array();

foreach($newArr as $s) {
    $k = array_search($s, $mergeArr);
    print_r($k);
    array_push($intArr, $k);
}
```

**Return output :** 3 25 33 26

**Expected output :** 3 25 33 36

36 since A is array_index 26

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: Updated up the question

Comment: Did you intend to write both "Return output : 3 25 33 26" and "Return output : 3 25 33 36"?

Comment: 4 ? I am getting it as 26 and thats driving me crazy...

Comment: @EllieKesselman my bad.. the lower one was expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any string in PHP will return true on `'string' == 0`, so you match the first 0, with index 26.

You should use the `$strick` parameter of `array_search` to be sure that 'Z' is treated as a letter.

However, it forces you to insert your integers value in `$newArr` as strict integers :

```
$mergeArr = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('0', '9'), range('A', 'Z'));
$newArr = array('d', 'z', 7, 'A'); // 7 instead of '7'
$intArr = array();

foreach($newArr as $s) {
    $k = array_search($s, $mergeArr, true); // $strict = true instead of default false
    print_r($k);
    array_push($intArr, $k);
}
```

Output :

`3 25 33 36`

Otherwise, you'll have to code your own `array_search` like function.

Comment: This works. I looked at the documentation and it said :  


* @param bool $strict [optional] <p>
*** If the third parameter strict is set to true then the array_search function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack. ***  according to which $strict check the types, not case. Right ?

Comment: *to be sure that 'Z' is treated as a letter* As what does it get treated when you don't set the third parameter to true?

Comment: Well, when i was not setting it as true, Z was always returning 26 as value while it should be returning 61. Even if it goes for Case_insensitive, it should have returned 25 (value of 'z'). The value 26 corresponded to character '0'

Comment: @CodeMonkey What I meant it that any string `== 0` in PHP. So it goes through the array, match the first 0, and return its key : 26. If you replace the `array_merge` with `range('0', '9'),range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z')` it will always match with 0, and return the key 0, even for lower letter. Its not related to the case.

Comment: @ClémentMalet That's what I wanted to see. Now only the link for the manual is missing which shows this too: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Interesting, so each string is a 0. That's new to me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ClémentMalet just realized with the strict=true, array_search is faling for 7 in dz7A

Comment: @CodeMonkey As I said, you also have to change the way you construct your `$newArr` check my answer again to see how. Or, just make your own array_search function, or put the integers range at the very end of your merge.